# Force node to wait for input before proceeding?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am making a turn based game using node as my server side code. The problem is I have no clue how to make the program wait for input before going onto another function. Preferably, I'd like it to wait for player 1's action, and once recieved, then wait for the next player until all turns are done.
Also, this just executes nextFunction immediately which makes sense after learning about asynchronous execution, but this is a case where I don't want that to happen.

```
    this._players.forEach((player, idx) => {
      player.on('turn', (turn) => {
        this._turns[index] = turn;
      });
    });
    nextFunction();
```

I attempted to use async, await, and also promises but I don't think I implemented them properly. I'm also not sure that .on() is even the way to go. On my client side, for reference, I have a few buttons that when pressed, emit an id which I can use server side to do logic on. I think .then() might help but it might make the code difficult to maintain and also keep track of while developing due to the amount of .then()'s I'll probably need to use. Is there a better way to code this in node?

Basically, I need my code to wait for user input before moving on.

Comment: Here is one way to structure it. Each game played has a game state, and one or more verbs (e.g. "attack" / "move") can mutate it. Give each game a unique name, perhaps a guid. Assign URLs, such as `http://localhost/mygame/move`. Players can POST to affect the state, and can GET when they want to display the current state. Next thing for you to decide is how to update other players when player-1 makes a move. They can learn about it some minutes later when they interact, or they can frequently poll the server, or you can have a pending request immediately notice the event.

Comment: This type of problem is what Events were invented for, and Websockets to keep the client updated with the server state. [Socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) is probably the most popular Node library for this. I would recommend reading their docs and checking out some examples of event-driven Node code.

Comment: Using `async`/`await` might or might not be appropriate, depending on what behaviour exactly you want. Can you [edit] your question to show us your attempt, please?

Comment: What are these `player` objects in your array? What are the `turn` events they fire?

Comment: "*I want to make the program wait for input before going onto another function. I'd like it to wait for player 1's action, and once recieved, then wait for the next player until all turns are done.*" - are "input", "action" and "turn" synonymous here? Please clarify. Also, what do you want to happen if the second player fires `turn` before the first player - do you just want to ignore the event when  it's not their turn?

Comment: The players are essentially socket.io id's, the turns are buttons that emit a string such as "raise" "call" "fold". I'll only enable a player's buttons if it is their turn. I think I need a way to wait until "turn" is emitted from the client side before executing any more code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`once`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#eventsonceemitter-name-options) to create a promise that waits for a single event. Then use that in your loop:

```
for (const [index, player] of this._players.entries()) {
  this._turns[index] = await once(player, 'turn');
}
nextFunction();
```